# WPF ScrollableViewer inside a part of an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to put a scrollable container on top of an image or inside it in WPF.
Then the user will be able to scroll the container while the image will be fixed. What I wan't to achieve exactly is to simulate the content of a smartphone. In this picture the smartphone is the image and the container seems to be inside this one :

What is the best practice to do it ?

[image: WPF container inside image]

Thanks !

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve from this image.

Comment: I edited my explanation to make the image clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the image - it has transparent corners - as the background of the containing Grid, and then put the `ScrollViewer` into the Grid and specify the margins from the edges.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="phone.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>        
    <ScrollViewer Margin="20, 30, 20, 30" Background="White"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can also set the margin of the `ScrollViewer` instead of giving the outer grid 3 columns and rows.

Answer (score 3):

you can put your Container inside  ScrollViewer tag:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" 
        Height="300" 
        Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="10,10,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
        <StackPanel>
           //Contorls like image ,button etc
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on your goal, but... if you want to basically have a static background image and put controls in front of it, one way is to put your Image and ScrollViewer in a 1x1 Grid as sibling children that both fill the space.  The second child will overlay the first.  e.g.

```
<Grid>
    <Image ... />
    <ScrollViewer Background="Transparent" ...>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Using a Transparent background brush will still allow the ScrollViewer (or other container) to process mouse input for clicking / hover / mousewheel purposes.  Alternatively, using {x:Null} will make a non-intercepting background and mouse input will be processed by the underlying Image control.